# grabbing text from input box and printing it with console.log

Tags: javascript, html

I have an element called `<input id="emailprotectionspamallinput" class="ms-SearchBox-field" type="text" value="">` where there is nothing inside the box at first.

I want to add some text to the input field, then grab the value from the text box. However the value seems to always come out to be null when perform a `console.log`

Here is the button that I want to trigger the value grabbing:

```
<button class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" style="float: left" id="get-getblacklistallemailinfor">
                  <span class="ms-Button-label">CONFIRM</span> 
                </button>
```

Here is the javascript that handles the button:

```
$("#get-getblacklistallemailinfor").click(getblacklistallemailinfor);
function getblacklistallemailinfor(){

  const emailvar = document.getElementById("emailprotectionspamallinput")
  const output = document.querySelector('div.enteremailinfoforblacklistall');
  console.log(emailvar)
  console.log(emailvar)
  console.log(output)


}
```

Here is a picture of what happens:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you were already using jquery you can get the input with:

`const emailvar = $('#emailprotectionspamallinput').val();`

I commented out your output as that is undefined. You did not provide a div with that name

```js
$("#get-getblacklistallemailinfor").click(getblacklistallemailinfor);
function getblacklistallemailinfor(){

  const emailvar = $('#emailprotectionspamallinput').val();
  //const output = document.querySelector('div.enteremailinfoforblacklistall');
  console.log(emailvar)
  console.log(output)


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="email" class="ms-SearchBox-field" type="text" value="">


<button class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" style="float: left" id="get-getblacklistallemailinfor">
<span class="ms-Button-label">CONFIRM</span> 
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Lord Beerus! I gotta catch up on Dragon Ball Super. What you suggested worked immediately. I will set this as the answer once the system allows me to. (3 minutes from now)

Comment: @user16660683 anytime!

Answer (score 0):

```
const output = document.querySelector('div.enteremailinfoforblacklistall');
```

Selects the first `div` with the class `enteremailinfoforblacklistall`, not any input element.

You can select your input element with

```
const output = document.querySelector("#emailprotectionspamallinput");
```

instead.

`output` will be an instance of `HTMLInputElement` in this case, [which possesses the `value` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

`value`: Returns / Sets the current value of the control.

To access what the user has input into the `output` element, use

```
output.value
```

which you can then also log to the console. It's just an attribute.

```
console.log(console.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" #box1 (keyup)="getName(box1.value)" placeholder="Your Name"/>

<input type="text" #box2 (keydown)="getName(box2.value)" placeholder="Your Name"/>

<input type="text" #box3 (keypress)="getName(box3.value)" placeholder="Your Name"/>

<input type="text" #box4 (blur)="getName(box4.value)" placeholder="Your Name"/>

<input type="text" #box5 (input)="getName(box5.value)" placeholder="Your Name"/>
```

Here, `getName` is a function.

Comment: Hi @Abhisek. You might want to fix the markup and provide the `getName()` function's body as well.

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.